# Android billing BAD_REQUEST

Tags: android, google-play, billing

I'm trying to purchase test item-id "android.test.purchased", to check my billing integration. But got the following error:

```
com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. 
Request=com.android.vending.model.GetImageRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST
```

Trace:

```
06-13 13:00:53.521: INFO/ActivityManager(30174): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.android.vending/.billing.InAppBuyPageActivity (has extras) }
06-13 13:00:54.101: INFO/ActivityManager(30174): Displayed activity com.android.vending/.billing.InAppBuyPageActivity: 514 ms (total 514 ms)
06-13 13:00:55.281: DEBUG/vending(21943): [26] BaseAction.run(): ApiException: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.GetImageRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST
06-13 13:00:55.281: ERROR/vending(21943): [26] BasePurchaseActivity.onPurchasePostError(): PurchasePost error
06-13 13:00:55.291: INFO/vending(21943): [1] BaseAction.displayErrorUi(): Server error in com.android.vending.billing.PurchasePostAction: com.android.vending.api.ApiException: Error from backend. Request=com.android.vending.model.GetImageRequest, Response=BAD_REQUEST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this error you need to upload your application to google market. But you don't need to publish it, just upload. https://market.android.com/publish/Home